# Can I recover a file in linux which i accidentally did an "rm" on?

Tags: linux, recovery, file-recovery

Do you know of any tools/commands by which I recover files which I accidentally removed?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You may be able to get help with this at one of the sites listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Comment: @mkal: you've been a member for 7 weeks, have asked and answered dozens of questions, and didn't know this was a site for programming questions?

Comment: I knew it was a site of programming questions for sure, but then there were tags of linux and reccovery. But Robert you are correct this was my bad.

Comment: You may be interested to know that Jeff plans on launching an "IT" StackOverflow in a couple of months, more information here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/coming-in-march-it-stack-overflow/.

Answer (score 8):

- Don't do anything on the partition; unmount it as it is;
- Install the [TestDisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk) suite, or boot from a live distribution with a recovery suite installed (see  the TestDisk wikipedia page);
- I found the [PhotoRec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhotoRec) utility very useful in similar situations (it was on a VFAT partition, but I guess it works also on ext2).

Answer (score 1):

How critical is it?  You can, but it's using forensics methods.  This means you'll want to unmount the drive, remount it read only and then use something like Helix to carve at the drive to recover it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to here about your troubles - I would start poking around for file recovery utilities but don't get your hopes up.

Are you using an ext3 file system?  If so then even file recovery utilities will not help you there - [here is some info on ext3](http://batleth.sapienti-sat.org/projects/FAQs/ext3-faq.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Sorry, but the whole point is that it is permanently deleted†. Given that you are asking this, you probably don't have something like [safe-rm](http://freshmeat.net/releases/287577/) installed.

† Kind of. Without forensic recovery tools, then yes.

Comment: Sorry, but you can.  Just not trivially.

Comment: When you have overwritten the whole file with random numbers about thirty times, *then* it is permanently deleted. Otherwise not.

Comment: Ouch! Oops - corrected. At least someone voted me up, so I haven't lost any rep! :D

Answer (score 0):

Better talk to your SA about recovering a backup.

Failing that, you are likely out of luck.